# How to print last repetitve row if next row has a higher value?

Tags: bash, awk

This is my first attempt to ask here. Help someone can help me on that.

What I need is to print the current row if second row gets higher. For example,

input file;

```
1  2  3 f
1  3  1 p
2  5  3 h
2  6  5 r
2  5  6 u
3  5  9 y
```

I want it as following:

```
1 3 1 p
2 5 6 u
3 5 9 y
```

I want to pick the first row in $1 if first row has same value as in second row of the first column

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please explain the logic why `2 5 6` is in output if 2nd column is the mark then `2 6 5` should come right? please explain us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` with `-u` only prints the first line, so use `tac` to make the last line the first:

```
<input.file tac | sort -k1,1 -u
```

Comment: So, should it be like that        tac | sort -k1,1 -u  inpt.txt> otput.txt

Comment: Man, Thanks a lot , you solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

or with awk

```
awk '{a[$1]=$0}END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' infile
```